# Syncing data between MySQL and Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, synchronization

In my project, I am storing a lot of data in MySQL automatically. I want, however, the same things to sync with Node.js application's own data storage. What would be the fastest and easiest way to do this when storing data in both storages simultaneously isn't possible?

So, for example, I am storing variable "balance" in MySQL inside one Node.js application. I would want this same balance updated into other Node.js application's own storage but my current Node.js app is not connected to socket or other kind of data transporting mechanism. So how could I fetch data from MySQL in that other Node.js application?

Answer (score 0):

sound look like your project structure is saga pattern.

in your question about update data is can use [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) to create a topic and 2 node application consume message on same topic to update data into own database.